Is there a way to test content warnings in python with yt-dlp?
I'm building a discord music bot and I want to know if there is a way to tell if the video is explicit.  I'm going to paste a very basic version of my code
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ee4QjCEHHc'
#the official audio of slide by calvin harris, an explicit song

ydl = YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestaudio', 'nonplaylist': 'True'})

info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

To clarify I'm not asking to test if the video is age protected, this song is an explicit song but not age protected, is there a way to see if the video is explicit?

Unless the uploader mentions it in the title or includes subtitles, I'd guess you need a transcriber with a list of bad words.
